# Display an img when rows are empty in MUI datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm using MUI V.5 with React.
And I would like to display an image in my grid, when rows are empty (when the user search for a product into the grid and can't find any result).
But I don't know how to access to this part `sin filas` (img reference)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LYO7.png)

```
      {products ? (
        <Box component="div" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            checkboxSelection={true}
            autoHeight
            density="comfortable"
          />
        </Box>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading</div>
      )}
    </>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new component and [override](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#slots) `noRowsOverlay` slot of MUI datagrid like this:

```
const MyCustomNoRowsOverlay = () => (
  <img src="/no-items-found.jpg" alt="no-item" />
);


<DataGrid
    slots={{
        noRowsOverlay: MyCustomNoRowsOverlay
    }}
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-empty-rows?file=src%2FApp.jsx) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: prop components is deprecated. See https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#component-name

Comment: @Rubinum thank you. I've updated the answer and the sandbox accordingly.